# Decomposition of multipliers explain

Tags: analysis

I can't figure out how I get result from decomposition of multipliers. Can you please explain? How this:
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{2x^2-3x+2}{x^3+x^2+x-3}$$
decomposed with $$x-1: 2x^2-3x+2$$
is equals to:
$$(x-1)(2x-1)$$
and how this $$x-1:x^3+x^2+x-3$$
decomposed is equals to: $$(x-1)(x^2+2x+3)$$
Where those values comes from, please explain. Thank you

Comment: $2x^2-3x+2\neq(x-1)(2x-1)=2x^2-3x+1$

Comment: It's the result of doing the polynomial division (in ways you can choose, e.g. classic the euclidean/long division). However, there's a quick method/scheme for divisions by a polynomial of the form $x-a$; check [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). Sometimes you can also quickly factor without explicitly performing the division.

Comment: Are you asking where the initial factors come from or how to do the division?

Comment: Similarly $x^3 + x^2 + x-3 \neq (x-1)(2x^2 + 2x + 3)$.

Comment: I do not understand those comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To factorize a polynomial, it is one of the tricks to select x such that the expression would be equal
 to zero.

Hence when $x=1, x^3+x^2+x-3=0$. 
Therefore $(x-1)$ is one of the factors of the given polynomial.> Hence when the polynomial is 
divided with $(x-1)$, we get $x^2+2x+3$.
 Also  $(x^3+x^2+x-3)=(x^3-1)+(x^2-1)+(x-1)=[(x-1)(x^2+2*x+3)]$

Since $(x^3-1)=(x-1)*(x^2+x+1)$ and $(x^2-1)=(x+1)*(x-1).$


Similarly the case of numerator as well :

$2x^2-3x+2=(x-1)(2x-2)$
Therefore the limit is:

$(2x-1)/(x^2+2x+3)$ as x tends to 1=1/6

Comment: This is well detailed answer,  thats really tries to explain,  but I still don't get it. Can you please post every step

Comment: Please post steps only on dividing part